# Vertex entering two times in DFS stack

Tags: c, graph, stack

I've a problem debugging my implementation of DFS in a undirected Graph.

During the run, the vertex 1 entered two times in the stack, and I really don't know why this happened.

I'm attaching my function here:

```
void dfsFromMatrix(uint64_t **matrix, unsigned vertexes, unsigned root) {
    unsigned *markedItems;
    stack *stackPointer;
    unsigned tempVertex;
    unsigned i;

    markedItems = (unsigned *) calloc(vertexes, sizeof(unsigned));
    stackPointer = NULL;

    stackPointer = stackPush(stackPointer, root);

    while (!checkIfStackIsEmpty(stackPointer)) {
        tempVertex = stackPointer -> data;

#ifdef _DEBUG_
    printf("tempVertex = %u\n", tempVertex);
#endif

        stackPointer = stackPop(stackPointer);
        if (!markedItems[tempVertex]) {
            markedItems[tempVertex] = 1;

#ifdef _DEBUG_
            printf("DFS: Marquei o vértice %u\n", tempVertex);
            printStack(stackPointer);
#endif

            for (i = 1 ; i <= vertexes ; i++)
                if (getValueFromMatrix(matrix, tempVertex, i)) {
                    stackPointer = stackPush(stackPointer, i);
                    printf("Entrei na fila: %u\n", i);
                }

        }
    }   
}
```

About the for loop. It really starts at one and ends in <= vertexes. The getValueFromMatrix function handles this, so I can use human understandable matrix positions.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: What is DFS? It appears not to be the same thing as the tag `dfs`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a graph with one vertex an a loop edge. Your algorithm pushes the root, marks it, then proceeds and pushes all the vertices connected to it, without checking if they are marked. The only vertex is connected to itself, so it gets pushed the second time.

The standard DFS algorithm pushes only unmarked vertices:

```
 pop top vertex T
 for all vertex V connected to T
    if V is not marked
      mark V
      push V
      process V
```

Observe that mark, push and process are all done at the same time. In your case, the process phase just prints out the vertex, but it could be anything.

Your algorithm pushes vertices that are connected to unmarked vertices:

```
 pop top vertex T
 if T is not marked
   mark T
   for all vertex V connected to T          
     push V
     process V
```

In your version mark and push are separated. It could work if you moved the process phase next to the mark phase, instead of next to the push phase.

```
 pop top vertex T
 if T is not marked
   mark T
   process T
   for all vertex V connected to T          
     push V
```

The standard algorithm is preferred, as it normally should be slightly faster.

Comment: I'm trying to implement as you said, but I'm failing miserably.

I've done: 
for (i = 1 ; i <= vertexes ; i++)
if (getValueFromMatrix(matrix, tempVertex, i)) {
if (!markedItems[i]) {
markedItems[i] = 1;
stackPointer = stackPush(stackPointer, i);
}

But isn't working correctly. I'm really missing something.

Comment: I think you are missing the way loops and arrays are working in C. Try `for (i = 0; i < vertexes; i++)`.

Comment: I was using i=1 to <= vertexes because my function: getValueFromMatrix  do the conversion from human understandable matrix to C matrix. It get the value and decreases 1. So in getValueFromMatrix, the position 0,0 is passed as 1,1.

Comment: This confuses the heck out of this human. Please don't do that, ever. C indexing is in use for more than 40 years. It works. 1-based indexing doesn't. Anyway, if you have a problem with this algorithm, I suggest you write up a separate questions, comments are not a good place for such discussion.